# Doctest not running tests

Tags: python, doctest

```
import doctest

def create_grid(size):
   grid = []
   for i in range(size):
       row = ['0']*size
       grid.append(row)
   """
   >>> create_grid(4)
   [['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0']]
   """
   return grid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
```

Running the above with `python Test_av_doctest.py -v` gives the following message:

```
2 items had no tests:
    __main__
    __main__.create_grid
0 tests in 2 items.
0 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Any idea why this error occurs?

Comment: Can you provide some more details?  What does your whole python file look like?  Are you using `doctest.testmod`?  Or are you using `doctest.testfile` and pointing it to the text file above?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that your `doctest`-formatted string isn't a docstring.

[Which docstrings are examined?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#which-docstrings-are-examined)

> The module docstring, and all function, class and method docstrings are searched.

If you move the testing string below the function definition, it will become a function docstring, and thus will be targeted by `doctest`:

```
def create_grid(size):
   """
   >>> create_grid(4)
   [['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0']]
   """
   grid = []
   for i in range(size):
       row = ['0']*size
       grid.append(row)

   return grid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
```

---

```
$ python Test_av_doctest.py -v
...
1 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized i am supposed to have the function inside a class. When i do the exact same thing as above it does not work, the only difference is that create_grid is now inside a class. I get the following error: NAmeError: name 'create_grid' is not defined

Comment: If you put a function "inside a class," it becomes a method. You need to make its first parameter the special `self` attribute, and refer to it as `self.create_grid()` within your docstring. I'd read up on [Python classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) for more.