# doctest not returning a result

Tags: python, testing, doctest

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177812/doctest-not-running-tests) question, and have seen [this](https://realpython.com/lessons/range-vs-enumerate/) tutorial, but still haven't been able to figure out what is going wrong.

I have the following code, just to try out doctest:

```py
import doctest

def fizz_buzz(numbers):
    """ 
    >>> numbers = [45, 22, 15, 39, 10]
    >>> fizz_buzz(numbers)
    >>> numbers
    ['fizzbuzz', 22, 'fizzbuzz', 'fiszssz', 'buzz']
    """ 

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        num = numbers[i]
        if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
            numbers[i] = 'fizzbuzz'
        elif num % 3 == 0:
            numbers[i] = 'fizz'
        elif num % 5 == 0:
            numbers[i] = 'buzz'
```

But when I run `python doctest.py -v` or `python3 -m doctest doctest.py` the code runs with no output, even though there should be an error message due to `fiszssz` in the testing.

I thought the issue might be that the file was called `doctest.py`, but even after renaming it to `othertest.py` it still produces no output.

What am I missing?

Comment: Note that you don't actually _run_ the tests in your file. `if __name__ = "__main__": doctest.testmod()` would allow `python yourfile.py`. You likely still have a `doctest.pyc` interfering with the other way of running it.

Comment: Amazing, I didn't realise the .pyc would affect it. Many thanks!